# Change redirect after registration error in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I wrote a plugin for joomla that adds custom fields to the user/register component. There are 3 different registration forms for different user groups.

The plugin acts on `onUserAfterSave()` and works fine, but there is one problem. When there is an error in the original user component, for example: "the username has already been taken" the form is redirected and neither `onUserAfterSave()` or `onUserBeforeSave()` is ever called.

I want to change that redirection, but without changing the core, but since neither plugin events are called, im not sure how to. Can you guys help me? Maybe I am missing something!

Is it possible to maybe override the save() function?

THANKS

Comment: I am not sure if that helps, but have you tried to increase the ordering of the plugin you wrote? In the plugin manager, if you choose as type user and click on joomla for instance, there is a dropdown for ordering, perhaps can you make your plugin trigger first by giving it a higher priority?

Comment: Hey Philipp, thanks for your reply, but this unfortunately doesnt solve anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem many times, so i can share a solution i use myself. If you don't want to edit Joomla core files, you can do the following:

1. Create your own template override of registration view.
2. Duplicate the **components/com_users/controllers/registration.php** file and lets say name it **registration2.php**
3. In your registration form override change hidden input's "task" value from registration.register to registration2.register
4. Feel free to override registration2.php classes how you like.

It's totally Joomla update proof, so you can update your joomla version witht worrying about errors.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably the way to go. It still feels like a hack, but at least it's update proof!

Comment: Well it's a hack, because natively Joomla doesn't allow to override core controllers or models :( Tell me how did it go, if you have any questions - i'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to do the checks that joomla is doing in your plugin and redirect in your plugin itself in the case that it wont pass. I see your predicament and I don't know a better way but I would pick a different event to run it on maybe even after page load and then on UI event in javascript.

Comment: Hey landed, thanks for your reply, but the thing is that the plugin events are never called. If I add `die()` to onUserBeforeSave and the other events nothing happens!

Comment: Thats what I mean you need a different event - you can listen to after page render perhaps. See here - http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events

I am not sure if to get that event the plugin needs to be a content type..try die() after ocs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentAfterDisplay

Answer (score 0):

The only clean way to extend the user registration/profile is to create a profile plugin like this one

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/plugins/user/profile/profile.php

You can extend com_users forms in backend and frontend.